# Gazebo vs. Bullet vs. Gpu

Tags: physics

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello all,
as Gazebo 1.9 can be used with Bullet engine 2.8 (http://gazebosim.org/w/index.php?title=Tutorials/1.9/bullet) and this version should support some physics acceleration on GPU (http://bulletphysics.org/wordpress/?p=340) is there any way how to benefit from GPU acceleration in simulator? Is there any flag or something to enable it or will it require some significant update of Gazebo code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5055/gazebo-vs.-bullet-vs.-gpu/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2013-11-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/14/zdenekm/) on 2013-11-22**:
Btw, is there any other possibility to offload some work to GPU other than gpu laser? And what speedup does the gpu laser provide? I know, to much questions together... :) But they are somehow related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Bullet 2.8 has experimental support for GPU acceleration, included in the [Extras/CUDA source folder](http://code.google.com/p/bullet/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FExtras%2FCUDA). Looking at the names of the source files, it appears to accelerate the broadphase collision detection, though I'm not sure if it accelerates anything else. Gazebo does not currently use this bullet functionality.

Of more interest may be the [bullet3 repository](https://github.com/erwincoumans/bullet3), which has the entire rigid body collision and dynamics pipeline implemented on a GPU. I've compiled and run the demos and they are quite impressive (depending on the GPU you have, of course). We don't yet support this physics engine, but I have created a [feature request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/963/add-support-for-bullet3-gpu-accelerated) for adding support for it.

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2013-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1